# Proving $\sqrt{x^2-xz+z^2} + \sqrt{y^2-yz+z^2} \geq \sqrt{x^2+xy+y^2}$ algebraically

Tags: inequality, solution-verification, radicals, geometric-inequalities, triangle-inequality

> The question is to prove that for any positive real numbers $x$, $y$ and $z$,
> $$\sqrt{x^2-xz+z^2} + \sqrt{y^2-yz+z^2} \geq \sqrt{x^2+xy+y^2}$$

So I decided to do some squaring on both sides and expanding:
$$\sqrt{x^2-xz+z^2} + \sqrt{y^2-yz+z^2} \geq \sqrt{x^2+xy+y^2}$$
$$x^2 -xz+z^2 +y^2-yz+z^2+2\sqrt{(x^2-xz+z^2)(y^2-yz+z^2)}  - x^2 - xy - y^2 \geq 0$$
$$2\sqrt{(x^2-xz + z^2)(y^2-yz+z^2)}\geq xz+yz+xy-2z^2$$
Squaring both sides yields
$$4(x^2-xz+z^2)(y^2-yz+z^2)\geq(xy+xz+yz-2z^2)^2$$
After some expanding it becomes
$$(xy-xz-yz)^2 \geq 0$$
which completes the proof.
However, I want to ask whether the squaring in the $3^{rd}$ - $4^{th}$step is problematic. Since it is possible for $xy + xz+ yz -2z^2$ to be negative. Squaring both sides will invert the sign. Do I have to analyse the positive and negative case here seperately?

Comment: Fortunately not: the left-hand side is definitely nonnegative, so if the right-hand side is negative, the inequality is automatically true! In other words, for this reason you might as well assume that the right-hand side is nonnegative when proceeding with the squaring step.

Comment: @Greg thanks for your answer! I missed such an obvious fact. But fortunately I asked it here before naively case-analysing it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**A Geometric Proof:**

Take a point $O$ in the plane and consider three line segments (this can be done since $x,y,z$ are positive real numbers) $OA, OB, OC$ with $$|OA|=x,|OB|=z,|OC|=y$$ and $$\angle AOB=60^{\circ},\angle BOC=60^{\circ}$$ therefore $\angle AOC=120^{\circ}$. In the triangle $\Delta ABC$ we have $$AB+BC\geq AC\tag{1}$$ Again by cosine rule  $$AB=\sqrt{x^2-xz+z^2}\\BC=\sqrt{y^2-yz+z^2}\\AC=\sqrt{x^2+xy+y^2}$$ Hence we get the desired inequality.

Comment: This was what I was taught too. Neat solution indeed! I am surprised that you came up with this so fast! Is it a well known technique or you've seen similar proofs before?

Comment: There is a possibility that the triangle $ABC$ is degenerate.  Therefore, in (1), the inequality sign should be $\geq $, rather than $>$.

Comment: @Batominovski you're right. Thanks!

Comment: @LearningMathematics actually the form $(a^2\pm ab+b^2)$ suggests me to consider cosine rule with angles $120^{\circ}$ or $60^{\circ}$

Comment: You can also use the algebraic version of the Triangle Inequality (i.e., a special case of the [Minkowski Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_inequality)): $$\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n\,a_i^2}+\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n\,b_i^2}\geq \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n\,(a_i+b_i)^2}\,.$$  (The solution below is actually equivalent to @ShubhrajitBhattacharya's solution.)

Comment: Note that
$$\begin{align}\sqrt{x^2-xz+z^2}&+\sqrt{y^2-yz+z^2}\\
&=\sqrt{\left(\frac{x}{2}-z\right)^2+\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}x\right)^2}+\sqrt{\left(z-\frac{y}{2}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}y\right)^2}\\
&\geq \sqrt{\left(\left(\frac{x}{2}-z\right)+\left(z-\frac{y}{2}\right)^\vphantom{2^2}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}x+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}y\right)^2}
\\&=\sqrt{\frac{(x-y)^2+3(x+y)^2}{4}}=\sqrt{x^2+xy+y^2}\,.\end{align}$$  (Observe that the inequality is true for all $x,y,z\in\mathbb{R}$ (not just positive values).

Comment: @Batominovski algebraization of geometric thoughts!

Answer (score 3):

You got that we need to prove that:
$$2\sqrt{(x^2-xz + z^2)(y^2-yz+z^2)}\geq xz+yz+xy-2z^2.$$
Now, by C-S $$2\sqrt{(x^2-xz + z^2)(y^2-yz+z^2)}=\sqrt{(2x^2-2xz+2z^2)(2y^2-2yz+2z^2)}=$$
$$=\sqrt{((x-z)^2+x^2+z^2)(z^2+y^2+(y-z)^2)}\geq$$
$$\geq(x-z)z+xy+z(y-z)=xy+xz+yz-2z^2$$ and we are done!

Now we see that the starting inequality is true for any reals $x$, $y$ and $z$.

Answer (score 1):

Let there be a triangle $ABC$ with vertices as $A(x,0), B(z/2,z\sqrt{3}/2), C(-y/2,y\sqrt{3}/2),$ then $$AB=\sqrt{x^2+z^2-xz},~ BC=\sqrt{y^2+z^2-yz}, ~CA=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+xy}.$$
Finally, the triangular inequality  $$AB+BC \ge CA.$$
proves the result. The equality holds when $A,B,C$ are collinear.